# literal string operation in rexx

Tags: mainframe, rexx

Hello Everyone I am new to rexx. can you please help me out with this string concatenation.

I have a string My Name is Raiza. and I need to add a single quote before and after Raiza . But I cant get it .

"My Name is " " 'Raiza' " how should I do this using rexx.

Comment: Please have a look at the following:

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZJDU_5.3.0/com.ibm.itnetviewforzos.doc_5.3/dqgl2mst25.htm

Comment: Thanks @DhruvSaxena

Answer (score 3):

try

```
  "My Name is '"NameVar"'"
```

---

In Rexx

```
  String1" "String 2" ==>  "String1 String 2"  == "String1" || " " || "String 2" 

  Var1 = "aaa"
  "String 1"Var1 ==> "String 1aaa"    == "String 1" || Var1
```

---

In rexx || is trhe concenation operator but a space between two Strings is eqivalent to || " " ||. If you place a variable next to a String (no white space)
it is equivalent to ||

So

```
   "Hi "user" welcome to rexx"
```

is the same as

```
   "Hi " || user || " welcome to rexx"
```

and

```
   "Hi" user "welcome to rexx"
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a say statement like this -

say "My Name is 'Raiza'"

should give the output as below:

My Name is 'Raiza'